# jQuery slideToggle menu that will collapse if 

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

anything except the link and the body of the exposed div are clicked after the event is fired and only after the event is fired

```
$(function() {
    $('#engageNetwork').bind('click', function() {
        $('.topNavSlide').stop(true,true).slideToggle(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
        $('a').click(function() {
            $('.topNavSlide').stop(true,true).slideToggle(500, 'easeOutExpo');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :not selector in order to bind the rest of the document click handler that will collapse the menu.
The selector and the binding is something like:

```
$(":not(#engageNetwork, #engageNetwork *)").bind("click", function(){
   $('.topNavSlide').stop(true,true).slideUp(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
});
```

(the second reference to #engageNetwork with the asterisk is in place to make sure any elements under the #engageNetwork won't be binded with this event handler.)